# Retrieve Firebase Data to UIPickerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

Is it possible to load Firebase data into the UIPickerView?
This is what I have and it works but I want to load a certain Firebase snapshot value into the picker instead of showing "0", "1", "2".

```
    if ([self.view.restorationIdentifier isEqualToString:@"picker_id"]){
        if ([Settings integerForKey:@"type"] == 4) {
            {
                // Database
                Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl: @"https://firebaseio.com/example"];

                // Read data and react to changes
                [ref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

                }];

            }

            pickerDistanceData = @[@"0",
                                   @"1",
                                   @"2",
                                   @"3"];

    }
    }
```

Do I have to set the snapshot.value to equal a certain index in the picker?

Comment: Please provide more insight about what you're trying to accomplish (i.e. what does the picker view do?). This seems generic and it's hard to give you a concrete answer. How is your data structured? How are you saving it to Firebase? You can show any type of value that is storable in Firebase, but you need to structure it correctly when saving.

Comment: I have text strings in Firebase that I want loaded up individually in the array instead of my example how I have "0","1","2","3".... The picker view just allows the user to select an item from the list but I want those items to be values that are currently stored in my Firebase. I'm not trying to save anything to Firebase, the strings are already on Firebase, I just want them loaded up on the picker view array so my question is how do I structure my 'pickerDistanceData' array so it can load the Firebase string? @wreckingcode

Comment: If the strings are already in Firebase, simply [query them](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) and you can put them in your `pickerDistanceData` array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *object=[snapshot.value objectForKey:@"Your Key"];

id var=@1;

for(var in object)
{

//put data to your pickerDistanceData

}
```